# Hover Opacity & Text Woes

Tags: css, opacity, css-sprites

I am trying to do a little optimization on my website and it has brought me to what seems to be a quite common topic but I haven't been able to find a problem quite like mine.

What I had. A image sprite (foggy/clear) and text on top of it. When you hovered over the image it could become clear, when you hovered over the text it would highlight and turn blue. (The image would remain clear)

What I want. To reduce the sprite into one image (rather than two in one), as it is the largest file on my main page and 57% of my load time is spent on images.

What I have done:

1) Gone from a sprite to just one clear image.

2) Created a new 'foggy-img' div container, placed it on top of the image, white with opacity: 0.15

3) Created a new div 'img-text' container for the text to put it outside the 'foggy-img' so the opacity doesn't effect it and have got it nicely place where it should be.

The Problem: It is small, the see-through box has replaced the sprite nicely and works. The text also highlights nicely. But. When one hovers over the text the see-through box becomes 'foggy' again.

Is there any way to keep the 'foggy-box' clear when hovering over the text which is in a separate div?

The HTML:

```
 <div id="photo-feature">
    <a href="services.html">
        <div id="img">
            <div id="photo-fog"></div>
            <div id="photo-text"><h3>Learn More...</h3></div> 
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#photo-feature a { text-decoration: none; }
#photo-feature #img { margin: 4px 5px 0 4px; width: 565px; height: 283px; background: url(images/photo-feature.png) 0 0; }

#photo-feature #img #photo-fog { height: 100%; background-color: #fff; opacity: 0.15; }
#photo-feature #img #photo-fog:hover { opacity: 0; }

#photo-feature #img #photo-text { position: absolute; margin-top: -34px; margin-left: 428px;}
#photo-feature #img #photo-text h3 { float: left; display: inline; color: #fff; }
#photo-feature #img #photo-text h3:hover { color: #0066cc; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Nope. These two effects are mutually exclusive. The only way to get a `:hover` effect on the `fog` div when the `text` div is hovered (with pure CSS) is to make `text` a child of `fog`. And, as you pointed out, that will affect the opacity of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use adjacent siblings selector.
([further details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors))
It doesn't work in older browsers though (guess which).

You would have to swap the ordering of your HTML a bit. Basically put the text first then use something like this:

```
#photo-text:hover + #photo-fog { // Do something
```

Right now you'd not be able to set the hover on the H3, but why not just style up the h3 rather than the #photo-text element then it would work fine.

**Edit:** Beautifully colour co-ordinated js fiddle for you to take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/will/Gt8KX/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hey, I've been trying to use your suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working. I altered your fiddle to resemble my img. Can you fiddle with it to make the box stay yellow when you hover over the text? (With the text also highlighting like it is). http://jsfiddle.net/uXRvH/

Comment: I've had to change the HTML a little, but it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/uXRvH/3/

Comment: Thanks so much! I was worried I had spent so much time just to hit a dead end, I had to play with the z-index but it works now and my website is all the faster for it. Appreciate the help :)